# Accessing structs in linked list (tree with a list of pointer to their children implementation)

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

I need to implement 3 functions (addElem, member and findPathCost) that operate on a tree with a list of pointers to the children with linked list. The struct treeNode defines the nodes in the tree, the childrenListElem defines the list of the treeNode's children.

```
struct tree::treeNode {
    Label label;
    Weight weight;
    childrenList children;   //pointer to the list of its children
};

struct tree::childrenListElem {
    treeNode* child;   //pointer to the first element of the children's list
    childrenListElem* next;  //pointer to the next one
};
```

In the header:

```
struct treeNode;             // forward declaration
typedef treeNode* Tree;      // pointer to root of tree
const Tree emptyTree = NULL; // empty tree

struct childrenListElem;                     // forward declaration
typedef childrenListElem* childrenList;      
const childrenList emptyChildrenList = NULL; // empty children list
```

My problem is that I can't access the children's list form the treeNode struct, here is an example in this auxiliary function for the addAlemen and member that I made:

```
//AUXILIARY FUNCTION: getNode(Label, Tree) returns the node with the given label in the tree.
//Used both in addElem and in member.

Tree getNode(Label & l, const Tree t)
{
    Tree aux = t;
    while (!isEmpty(aux)) {
        if (aux->label == l)
            return aux;
        aux = (aux->children)->next; //HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
                                     //usually I would have just done
                                     //aux = aux->NextVertex
                                     //(with NextVertex being the next
                                     //treeNode in the tree t);
                                     //but I can't seem to access the
                                     //second struct as the compiler
                                     //tells me that "children" is
                                     //apparently not a pointer.
                                     //How can I access the second struct?
    }
    return emptyTree;
}
```

Here is the error my compiler shows:

```
 The error is: "error: cannot convert 'tree::childrenListElem*' to 'tree::Tree' {aka 'tree::treeNode*'} in assignment aux = aux->children->next;"
```

When I instead put aux = aux->children.next; I am shown this error (I am using the gcc compiler):

```
The error is: "error: request for member 'next' in 'aux->tree::treeNode::children', which is of pointere type 'tree::childrenList' {aka 'tree::childrenListElem*'} (maybe you meant to use '->'?)
```

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us. What is `Tree`?

Comment: How is `childrenList` defined? Is it actually the same as `childrenListElem`?

Comment: Maybe the solution is as simple as `aux->children.next`?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not! I've also tried (aux.children)->next, nothing!

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: By the code you've shown, `aux->children` should be an expression of type `childrenListElem*`. Are those typedefs visible where `getNode` is defined?

Comment: The error is: "error: request for member 'next' in 'aux->tree::treeNode::children', which is of pointere type 'tree::childrenList'  {aka 'tree::childrenListElem*'} (maybe you meant to use '->'?)

Comment: so yes, `aux->children->next` should work. Are you sure you're editing (and saving!) the file your compiler is complaining about?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I checked twice. Also, here is the error my compiler shows when I use aux=aux->children->next: error: cannot convert 'tree::childrenListElem*' to 'tree::Tree' {aka 'tree::treeNode*'} in assignment aux = aux->children->next;

Comment: That is correct. `aux->children->next` has type `childrenListElem*`. `aux->children->next->child` has type `treeNode*` (which you typedef'd to `Tree`)

Comment: It means that `aux->children->next->child ` will now be pointing to the next treeNode, right? (thank you!)

Comment: Correct. Are you sure you do not want to do anything with `aux->children->child`? (the first element of the `children` linked list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## (edited) short answer:

After trying to compile your example, I noticed, that children is in fact not a instance of childrenListElem but a pointer and your way of accessing it is correct. Sorry, got a bit confused with those typedefs.
But you try to assign the value of

```
(aux->children)->next
```

which is of type childrenListElem* to a variable of type Tree aka treeNode*. After changing it to

```
aux = (aux->children)->child;
```

it compiled on my pc, also with gcc.

## (Old and wrong) short answer:

Use the dot-operator.

```
aux = aux->children.next;
```

## (now wrong) Explanation:

If we break down this one statement it becomes something like this:

```
aux = aux->children->next;
//can also be written like the following to lines:

childrenList child = aux->children;
//1. dereference aux and retrieve the member children
//the result is instance of childrenList

aux = child->next
//2. dereference child and retrieve member next.
//this fails, because child is not a pointer
```

## (kind of maybe still helpful) Extended Answer:

Maybe you have just confused the '->'-operator with '.'-operator, which happens a lot to me :)
Or you have a general misunderstanding of pointers and members. In that case maybe this short example will help you:

```
struct a;

struct b
{
   //this is a full instance of a
   a instanceOfA;
   // this is just a pointer to an instance of a
   a* pointerToA;
}

void foo()
{
    b instanceOfB;
    //members of an instance are always accessed with the dot-operator:
    a instanceOfA = instanceOfB.instanceOfA;
    a *pointerToA = instanceOfB.pointerToA;

    //if you have a pointer you need to use the -> operator
    b *pointerToB = new b();
    instanceOfA = pointerToB->instanceOfA;
    pointerToA = pointerToB->pointerToA;

    //The -> operator is just the shortcut for dereferencing + member access
    //It does the same like this:
    instanceOfA = (&pointerToB).instanceOfA;
    pointerToA = (&pointerToB).pointerToA;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem and also clarifies some details :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I understood everyting perfectly and I did in fact confuse the 2 operators, but somehow the compiler still says it is wrong (I am using the gcc compiler)!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I overlooked one of the typedefs and edited my answer. With a small change it compiles on my pc now. Anyway I don't know why the comiler gives you such a strange message.